# Assigning the value of P1_tem, depending on what is selected in the checkbox

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-apex

I have a checkbox in oracle apex , there I choose the role of the user. I want the dependencies where there is a tick, I had a value for P_tem! I tried but it did not work, can you help ??

```html
DECLARE
BEGIN
    IF :P30_ROLE_ID = 'Admin' THEN -- checking for the difference
       :P30_NAME :=  '30';
  else 
        IF :P30_ROLE_ID = 'Reader' THEN -- checking for the difference
       :P30_NAME :=  '20'; 
    END IF;
   else 
        IF :P30_ROLE_ID = 'user' THEN -- checking for the difference
       :P30_NAME :=  '10'; 
  END IF;
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: There are syntax errors in your code. You need to use `ELSIF` instead of something like `END IF; else`.

Answer (score 0):

If the item is a checkbox based on a list of values, the user might choose multiple values, so you need to cater for this possibility. The values will be separated by colons (:), e.g. `Admin:Reader`.

For example:

```
IF instr(':' || :P30_ROLE_ID || ':', ':Admin:') > 0 THEN
   :P30_NAME :=  '30';
elsif instr(':' || :P30_ROLE_ID || ':', ':Reader:') > 0 then
   :P30_NAME :=  '20'; 
elsif instr(':' || :P30_ROLE_ID || ':', ':User:') > 0 then
   :P30_NAME :=  '10'; 
END IF;
```

Comment: Thank you, I did as you wrote, but it didn't help, I did the dynamic action / change P30_ROLE_ID / set value / Items to Submit P30_ROLE_ID
Affected Elements / P30_NAME

Comment: When I check the variable on the browser page with the help of the command in the console $ v ('P30_ROLE_ID'), I see the correct answer, such as "Admin"

Comment: I think it makes sense for you to create a small sample app on apex.oracle.com and let us have a look at what it is you are trying to achieve. With the limited description you have provided it is hard to give you a detailed solution.